# What is difference between QTimer timeout slot calling a slot through direct connection or queued connection?

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer, qapplication

I'm asking in a case where there is a lot of qt events queued in event engine. Does `QTimer` emit `timeout()` signal through event and will with `queuedConnection` to a slot create another event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slots connected with `Qt::DirectConnection` will be called immediately when the `QTimer::timeout` signal is emitted by `QTimer`. If you use a queued connection, it will schedule an event to call the slot, which will be processed by the event loop. `QTimer` uses [`timerEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#timerEvent) to [emit the `timeout` signal](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qtimer.cpp.html#_ZN6QTimer10timerEventEP11QTimerEvent).

Comment: Just a quick question: does this mean, when using `Qt::DirectConnection`, if the program is in the middle of running function `A` and the timeout signal is emitted, then execution of `A` is paused, the connected slot to timeout signal is executed, and after finishing executing it, the execution of `A` is resumed? Let's assume both `A`, timer and the connected slot belong to the same thread.

Comment: And is this the case with all connections of type `Qt::DirectConnection`? I am a little confused about this because everywhere I read, the **direct connection** is explained as "[the slot] will be called immediately when signal is emitted" or "it is like a function call". Actually, now I tested this on `QTimer`, but it seems that in this case the direct connection is like queued connection (both `QTimer` and the connected slot lived in the same thread in my test). I don't not understand their difference?!

Comment: @today That is because the `timeout` signal is emitted in the `timerEvent` event handler. This event is processed in the thread where the `QTimer` object lives in. And if function `A` is being executed, the application will wait for it to finish before starting to handle events. But if you create your timer in a different thread and use `Qt::DirectConnection`, then the slot will be executed immediately, regardless if `A` is being executed or not, and it will be executed in the thread where the timer lives in. So be careful.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not queued connection by default unless it is running in a different thread. Therefore it is DirectConnection.

I would say that, in general, if you want to guarantee a sequential order of events you are better of using Qt::QueuedConnection with things like timers even when in the same thread so that the event goes onto the queue and is not just acted upon immidiatley - since this behaviour is some-what more like an "interrupt".

However if you really want the timer timeout() to be acted on immediately then use Qt::DirectConnection - I feel that you need to be more careful with this connection type in general (with things like timers which can trigger in the middle of other normal code).

**Edit**

By "normal code" I mean...well, see comments below:

Comment: Timers can't trigger in the middle of normal code. Timers are triggered by an event. That is why it needs an event loop to work. The docs state: [`For QTimer to work, you must have an event loop in your application; that is, you must call QCoreApplication::exec() somewhere. Timer events will be delivered only while the event loop is running.`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/timers.html).

Comment: I mean "normal" as in assuming running in a Qt program - therefore exec() will have run, sorry should not have assumed that - will correct that :)

Comment: So "in the middle of normal code" still means 
when the QCoreApplication gets free time to execute events 
and not 
during a function execution?

Comment: I don't see why would you have to be careful when using direct connection, as the slots are still only triggered when the application/thread goes back to the event loop. It basically acts like calling a slot with a queued connection, hence why people tend to use `QTimer::singleshot(0, object, &Object::slot);` to call functions "queuedly".

Comment: @thuga But this is what I am saying, you won't jump the queue by using QueuedConnection, you may if you use direct...

Comment: It is not really decided at connect time whether it uses queued or direct connection afaik. But always reevaluated at time of emission of signals.

Comment: What do you mean `jump the queue`?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That is true, at least for `Qt::AutoConnection`. Emitting a signal results in [`QMetaObject::activate` call, which checks the specified connection type](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp.html#3688). If `Qt::AutoConnection` was specified, it will check the thread affinities of the emitting and the receiving threads. If they are the same, it uses a direct connection, and if they are different, it uses a queued connection.

Comment: @thuga I mean, when the signal occurs it would get acted upon immediately instead of being added to the event queue.

Comment: But since it is called from the event queue, why does it matter? What will you gain by telling it to process the slot later? It is like having a slot you call with a queued connection, in which you only emit a signal which is connected to another slot via a queued connection.

Answer (score 0):

When a QTimer times out, every Signal-Slot connection, which joins signal of this QTimer with an slot, fires this slot exactly one time.